# unable to print borders of table using window.print() function

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, printing

I am currently working on a wordpress plugin in which I have a table as follow

```
<table class="responsive display table table-bordered"><tbody><tr><th>Subject</th><th>Total Marks</th><th>Obtained Marks</th></tr><tr><td> 1 . sdf</td><td>99</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td> 2 . sdf</td><td>23</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><th>Total</th><th>122</th><th>50</th></tr></tbody></table>
```

This is wrapped in a div `print`

I am printing this with the following jS

```
<script>
function print_this()
{
       var divToPrint = document.getElementById('print');
       var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=3600,height=500');
       popupWin.document.open();
       popupWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + divToPrint.innerHTML + '</html>');
       popupWin.document.close();
}
</script>
```

But whenever I am trying to print it, it does not print any of the table border. How can I print the table borders also :

Comment: put border=1 in table tag

Comment: thanks and is there any option that I can set it on A4 Size paper sheet and page orientation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery also. Try it(not tested it.)

```
$('table.responsive display table table-bordered').css('border','1');
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try to use the print **CSS**.
I think it should be easier to set with the **CSS** what you want to print and then just use

```
window.print()
```

to print it.